Doubt about the way cardinality is defined
By definition, we have $|A|\le|B|$ iff there exists an injection between $A$ and $B$. Furthermore, if $|A|\le|B|$ and $|B|\le|A|$, then $|A|=|B|$ (that is, there exists a bijection between $A$ and $B$). The latter result is known as Schröder–Bernstein theorem.
My question is: is the property $n\le m\land m\le n\implies n=m$ proved by this statement? The way my algebra book constructed the natural numbers, it didn't need sets at all to prove it. Why isn't it enough to prove the theorem?
I think I just have a huge confusion about the formal differences between sets like cardinal numbers and natural numbers, but I really don't get it. Which one of these results is more "fundamental" and how are they related? Maybe the order over the natural numbers is defined differently than that over the cardinal numbers? Why? Aren't natural numbers isomorphic to finite cardinal numbers, and so the order relationship is "inherited"?
EDIT: Let me clarify my question, which was phrased quite poorly. One can define a bijection between the set of finite cardinal numbers $\mathcal S$ and $\mathbb N$, say $f\colon\mathcal S\to\mathbb N$. Then, given that an order over $\mathbb N$ is defined by other means, why can't I just define $n\le m\iff f(n)\le f(m)$ for all $n,m\in\mathcal S$?
EDIT 2: My book (An introduction to algebraic structures by Joseph Landin) defined natural numbers as
$$\mathbb N := \bigcap_{H\in\mathscr E}H$$
Where $\mathscr E := \{H\subset\mathbb R \mid 0\in E\land x\in H\implies x+1\in H\}$. It had already defined $\mathbb R$ through the field axioms.
It defines the positive cone $P$ of the real numbers axiomatically and then defines $x<y\iff y-x\in P$ and $x\le y\iff x<y\lor x=y$.
The order relation is inherited by $\mathbb N$, being it a subset of $\mathbb R$.

The cardinalities $\lvert \mathbb N\rvert$ and $\lvert \mathbb R\rvert$ for example are not natural numbers

and inheritance applies to subobjects

the property you asked can be proved with sets. There could be other ways as well, such as the way your text used but this doesn't mean the set theoretic proof is not enough

@J.W.Tanner I added an edit

How exactly did your text define the natural numbers and their order relation? It will be challenging to answer your question without knowing this.

Regarding your edit, while you say that "One can clearly define" that bijection $f : \mathcal S \to \mathbb N$, nonetheless if you think about it you may appreciate that formulating the definition of $f$ and proving it's requisite properties actually takes a bit of work.

@LeeMosher but it exists... right? My life has been a lie if it doesn't.

I did not say that it does not exist. What I said is that there is a theorem that it exists, and that theorem has a proof, and that proof consists of more work than just writing down the word "clearly".

@LeeMosher oh, okay then. You're right, I assumed that fact without providing a proof. I'll remove that word.

@CameronBuie I added another edit

Long before Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein, people knew that if $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\leq y, y\leq x$ that means $x=y$.

@Michael so for finite sets the theorem isn't anything new?

@Elvis yes. Obviously.

There is one bijection $f\colon\mathcal S\to\mathbb N$ for which it makes sense to say $n\le m\iff f(n)\le f(m)$. There are infinitely many bijections that "shuffle" the order of the cardinals in some way.

Given sets $A,,B$, we write $A\preceq B$ if $A$ can be injected into $B$, and $A\approx B$ if $A$ can be bijected with $B$. The Schröder–Bernstein theorem states $A\preceq B\land B\preceq A\iff A\approx B$. The aim of defining cardinals is to assign to $A$ a "cardinal" $|A|$ so $|A|=|B|\iff A\approx B$, and order cardinals so $|A|\le|B|\iff A\preceq B$. It turns out this can be done, so $|A|\le|B|\land|B|\le|A|\iff|A|=|B|$. But since cardinals only make sense because of the Schröder–Bernstein theorem, it's not proved using them, and is best not thought of as a statement about them.

Since the order relation $\leq$ on $\Bbb R$ thus defined is antisymmetric (meaning that if $x,y\in\Bbb R$ such that $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x,$ then $x=y$)--which can be proved from field and positive cone axioms and definitions--and since $\Bbb N$ is defined as a subset of $\Bbb R,$ then there is no need for set-theoretic cardinality results to conclude the desired result.
That said, there are many different ways to define the natural numbers. One common option in set theory is as the finite von Neumann ordinals. Cardinalities, set-theoretically speaking, are equivalence classes comprised of sets which are in bijection with each other; the natural numbers (defined set theoretically as von Neumann ordinals) are generally taken to be the canonical representatives of the finite cardinalities, though other representatives could be chosen instead for any cardinality (other than that of the empty set, of course). In the context of von Neumann ordinals, we can define a relation $\leq$ by $\alpha\leq\beta$ if and only if $\alpha\in\beta$ or $\alpha=\beta.$ Since von Neumann ordinals are well-ordered (and so strictly totally ordered) by $\in,$ then this relation $\leq$ is a non-strict total order among such ordinals, so is a partial order, and so is antisymmetric. Again, then, there is no need for the Schröder-Bernstein theorem among natural numbers in this context.
The Schröder-Bernstein theorem is needed instead in order to prove that the relation $\leq$ among arbitrary sets (defined by the existence of an injective function, as you mentioned in your post) is antisymmetric.
